# How to concatenate two kotlin flows?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

As stated, I'd like to concatenate two flows sequentially therefore `merge` won't work.

Example:

```kotlin
val f1 = flowOf(1, 2)
val f2 = flowOf(3, 4)
val f = concatenate(f1, f2) // emits 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: If there are two flows defined like the following: `val f1 = flowOf(1, 2, 3 ,4)
val f2 = flowOf(5, 6)`, do you want to combine them and get the result `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`?

Comment: yep, sequential concatenation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `flattenConcat` for this:

```
fun <T> concatenate(vararg flows: Flow<T>) =
    flows.asFlow().flattenConcat()
```

Or the `flow` builder:

```
fun <T> concatenate(vararg flows: Flow<T>) = flow {
    for (flow in flows) {
        emitAll(flow)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work: [onCompletion](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-completion.html)

```
val f1 = flowOf(1,2,3)
val f2 = flowOf(4,5,6)
val f = f1.onCompletion{emitAll(f2)}
runBlocking {
   f.collect {
        println(it)
   }
}

//Result: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```